# Sufficient condition for $ Iso(G/H) \cong G \times N_G(H)/H $

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

Let $ G $ be a compact connected semi-simple Lie group. Then the Killing form defines a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $ G $, call it $ g $. Let $ H $ be a closed subgroup of $ G $ and equip $ G/H $ with the push forward of the bi-invariant Riemannian metric $ g $, which we also call $ g $. So
$$
G \to G/H
$$
is a Riemannian submersion. What is a sufficient condition for
$$
\text{Iso}(G/H,g) \cong G \times (N_G(H)/H)
$$
to hold?

Lemma 1.2 of the Shankar article linked by C.F.G. seems to suggest that if $ G $ is simple with trivial center then $ \text{Iso}(G/H,g) $ is at least $ G \times (N_G(H)/H) $. However if $ H $ is trivial then the isometry group may be strictly larger than that. For example when $ G=SO_{2n+1}(\mathbb{R}) $ then $ \text{Iso}(G) $ is a semidirect product
$$
\text{Iso}(G,g) \cong (G \times G) \rtimes C_2
$$
see for example Theorem 2.5/Remark 2.6 of

https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.06413

So my original thought was that if $ G $ is simple, compact with trivial center and $ H $ is nontrivial then
$$
Iso(G/H,g)\cong G \times N_G(H)/H
$$
Motivation:

If we take $ G=SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $
Then
$$
Iso(SO_3(\mathbb{R})/H,g)\cong G \times N_{SO_3(\mathbb{R})}(H)/H
$$
for every nontrivial closed subgroup $ H $ of $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $. See for example

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010077

However this guess seems to be wrong. Consider the answer from Jason DeVito (this is just his second comment)

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2610748/758507

This shows that we can take $ G $ to be the exceptional group $ G_2 $ (which is indeed simple and compact with trivial center). Then pushing forward the bi-invariant metric $ g $ onto
$$
G_2/SU(3)\cong S^6
$$
we just get the round metric so
$$
Iso(G_2/SU_3,g) \cong O_7(\mathbb{R})
$$
So if my conjecture is correct then
$$
G_2 \times N_{G_2}(SU_3)/SU_3 \cong O_7(\mathbb{R})
$$
in other words $ N_{G_2}(SU_3)/SU_3 $ is a seven dimensional group. This is clearly false since it contradicts the simplicity of $ G_2 $.

At this point I'm not really sure what to say. I would still like a sufficient condition. But I'm not sure what that sufficient condition would be.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75742/isometry-group-of-a-homogeneous-space/75887#75887.  Robert's Bryant answer there tells how to compute the Lie algebra of the isometry group, but not the full group of components.  I don't know of any general method for computing the full group of components.

Comment: I've seen that question before it's a great question but I don't think this is really a duplicate because I'm asking something very specific claiming the isometries are $ G $ times $ N_G(H)/H $. And it doesn't seem obvious to me that Robert Bryant provides an immediate answer to that claim. But thanks for linking that question I should have done that to start with

Comment: Yeah, I didn't vote to close because it's only "kind of" a duplicate.   Does my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625457/riemannian-metrics-on-homogeneous-spaces help?

Comment: Related paper:[Isometry groups of homogeneous spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0926-2245(00)00038-3)